# white space on top of UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I need to add a UITabBarController as subView. But I can't remove the white space on top. Does anybody know a solution?

[image]

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do..

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate = self;
[tabBarController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
```